# How do I propagate a component parameter binding upstream?

Tags: data-binding, parameters, blazor, .net-8.0

Here's the code:

**TestComponentA.razor**

```
<div style="border: 1px solid; padding: 4px;">
    <input @bind-value=this.TestParamA />
    Test Param A: @this.TestParamA
</div>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string TestParamA { get; set; } = null!;
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> TestParamAChanged { get; set; }
}
```

**TestComponentB.razor**

```
<div style="border: 1px solid; padding: 4px;">
    <TestComponentA @bind-TestParamA=this.TestParamB></TestComponentA>
    Test Param B: @this.TestParamB
</div>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string TestParamB { get; set; } = null!;
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> TestParamBChanged { get; set; }
}
```

**Home.razor**

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>
<div style="border: 1px solid; padding: 4px;">
    <TestComponentB @bind-TestParamB=this.TestParamC></TestComponentB>
    Test Param C: @this.TestParamC
</div>
@code {
    public string TestParamC = "45";
}
```

After the page loads, this is the result after typing `test` into the input:

[image]

I need the text input to propagate up from the innermost component to the topmost. How do I do this?

Comment: My fallback will be to handle bindings with an injected service. Do I need to resort to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `@bind:get` and `@bind:set` attributes,

`Foo.razor`:

```
<input @bind:get="FooString" @bind:set="s => OnSet.InvokeAsync(s)"/>

@code {
    
    [Parameter]
    public string FooString { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> OnSet { get; set; }
    
}
```

`Bar.razor`:

```
<Foo FooString="@BarString" OnSet="OnSet"/>
<p>BarString is @BarString</p>

@code {
    
    [Parameter]
    public string BarString { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> OnSet { get; set; }
    
}
```

`Baz.razor`:

```
<Bar BarString="@_value" OnSet="OnSet"/>
<p>Baz value is @_value</p>

@code {

    private string _value = "hello world";

    private void OnSet(string value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

}
```

This will propagate the new value of the input field upward and trigger a rerender for all the components in the hierarchy.

Comment: Nice. I found out `CascadingParameter` also exists, but this will suffice for now.

Comment: @Mark Gross the reason your example works is that you have removed the `@bind-` syntax from the call stack. My (now deleted) answer went to some length to explain why this is the case. All you are doing now is passing an event callback through the stack. The trick is to manually invoke the event handler in the leaf component - which is what you are doing in `@bind:set`, and I was doing in @oninput.

Comment: A further note to this example is that you can use `@bind:event` to choose when the event is fired. In the case on an `input` you are most likely to want to choose between `oninput` and `onchange`

Comment: @hamstar This is not a use case for `CascadingParameter` - that is a one-way cascade of data from some container to some descendant(s)